# How to override navigation zone on orchard cms blog but not blog post?

Tags: orchardcms

How do I override the zone-navigation zone in Orchard on the main blog page only. I'd like to leave the blog post page alone.

I would like to edit the Menu (remove it) but keep the menu on the blog post pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put that menu widget in a layer that only applies to blog post pages.  I don't think there is a built-in layer rule for content types, but you could implement one.  See IRuleProvider in the Orchard.Widget module.  Alternatively, you could just use the url rule if there is something consistent in the url for your blog posts.  There is a link to create a new layer in the widgets admin area.  Your rule would look something like this...

```
url '~/MyBlog*'
```

Then just put your widget in that layer.

Additionally, if you don't want any of the zone to be rendered when there are no shapes in it, make sure to check the Model.ZoneName for null in your Layout.cshtml from your theme.

```
@if (Model.Navigation != null) {
  <div id="navigation">@Display(Model.Navigation)</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. It would accomplish something similar to what I was hoping to do. Still hope I can find a way to enable and disable zone-navigation for each page like you can with shapes.

Comment: You mean you want to disable a zone named 'navigation-zone'?  What do you mean by that? Just not render anything in it?  Sorry, I'm just trying to understand what you mean and why you need it.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to render anything in that zone on the home page but still render the menu on each blog post.

Comment: I would do the layer logic above, and then just make sure that you check the model for null before rendering the zone in your layout.  I'll update the answer with the additional code.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I added the Advanced Menu widget to the navigation zone and removed it from the homepage layer.